# How Android CornerPathEffect is formed?

Tags: android, view, graphics

I have a question about Android CornerPathEffect. From the function description, I still can't understand how the corner is formed based on the radius parameter. It would really help if you attach a description picture with your answer, thanks in advance!

```
package android.graphics;

public class CornerPathEffect extends PathEffect {

    /**
     * Transforms geometries that are drawn (either STROKE or FILL styles) by
     * replacing any sharp angles between line segments into rounded angles of
     * the specified radius.
     * @param radius Amount to round sharp angles between line segments.
     */
    public CornerPathEffect(float radius) {
        native_instance = nativeCreate(radius);
    }

    private static native long nativeCreate(float radius);
}
```